# Querying the same value from the same table with two JOINS or two ONs

Tags: mysql

Does that question even make sense?

I'm trying to do a Query where it pulls 2 different values from a JOIN on the same table.

I have and "Order" where there are two values, "TakenBy" & "PackedBy" These are User_IDs from a table for Employees. Most of the time they will not be the same.

How do I seporate them in the query? I can get one of them fine, but I am unsure how to retreave both values.

Here what I have for getting one..

```
SELECT
O.Order_ID AS OID, Customer_ID AS CID, Emp.UserName AS UserName
FROM Orders O
LEFT JOIN Employees Emp ON Emp.User_ID = O.User_ID
WHERE O.Customer_ID =3
```

But, what about when I want the "PackedBy?" also how do I get that too?

```
[Employees Table]
[User_ID] [UserName]
[1]       [Joe]
[2]       [Bill]
[3]       [Bobby]
[4]       [Steve]

[Orders]
[Order_ID] [Customer_ID] [TakenBy] [PackedBy]
[10]       [55]          [3]       [1]
[11]       [66]          [2]       [4]
[12]       [77]          [3]       [4]
[13]       [88]          [2]       [1]
```

I want the Query to return somthing like

```
[OID]   [CID]   [TAKER] [PACKER]
[11]    [66]    [Bill]  [Steve]
```

Comment: Add a join to the `Employees` table, using a different alias & criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use different table aliases, you could join the same table more than once.

For example:

```
SELECT
O.Order_ID AS OID, Customer_ID AS CID, 
   EmpP.UserName AS Packer,
   EmpT.UserName AS Taker

FROM Orders O
LEFT JOIN Employees EmpP ON Emp.User_ID = O.PackedBy
LEFT JOIN Employees EmpT ON Emp.User_ID = O.TakenBy
WHERE O.Customer_ID =3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two joins, one for each employee role:

```
SELECT O.Order_ID AS OID, Customer_ID AS CID, Emp.UserName AS UserName,
       packed.UserName as PackedBy
FROM Orders O LEFT JOIN
     Employees Emp
     ON Emp.User_ID = O.User_ID left join
     Employees Packed
     on Packed.User_id = o.PackedBy
WHERE O.Customer_ID =3
```